# how to rearrange a contents type in view?

Tags: views, 8

I have created a view using 8 content type ,then i choose

page display setting

```
 Display format :Grid full post

Settings :number of columns 2
Alignment : vertical
```

Then view like

```
 Content A           content D
    Content B           Content E   
    Content C           content F
                        content G
```

But i want a grid view like

```
 Content A      content E    
    Content B      Content F          
    Content C      content G
    content D
```

How can i rearrange contents as grid in view?is it possible?please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has to do with the content size and CSS that is creating the layout using floats.

You can use other CSS methods for layout that allow for far more control over positioning, but I'm not aware of any ready-made solutions for that. To modify the CSS you need to create a subtheme if you're not already using it, to override the theme with new code, or use a module like [CSS Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_editor).

You can get CSS layout help in other places specialized for that, that isn't a Drupal-related question.